# Unfocus window with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I know I'm not the first one having a hard time trying to upload a document from Windows file explorer with Selenium (I've done this before), but this app is *weirdly* done.

Basically, you click on an `input` element, and on keyup, a Windows file explorer appears.

In my test, I populate the clipboard and try to send the file path in the Windows file explorer input (which *seems* to be focused):

```
String myString = text;
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v")).perform();
action.build().perform();
```

Unfortunately, it's the browser input that receives the pasted text.

I'm willing to unfocus this input, so maybe the text will be pasted in the Windows file explorer input.

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Robot helped me get out of this problem.

```
try {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `Actions action = new Actions(driver);` should have given me a hint: if we're messing around with the driver, then it's impossible to mess around with the Windows file explorer.